# Scala Dataframe.columns - Order of columns

Tags: dataframe, scala

How to get the columns in the same order as they are in the dataframe?

```
val df = Seq(("1", "2", "a"), ("3", "4", "b"), ("5", "6", "d")).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")

df.printSchema()
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: string, col2: string ... 1 more field]
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)


df.columns
Array[String] = Array(col1, col2, col3)
```

`dataset.columns` gives the columns and they seem to be in the same order but I could not find any documentation as to this will be the case always. Can we rely on this method to get the columns in the same order as they are in dataset?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we rely on this method to get the columns in the same order as they are in dataset?

Yes

---

The definition of [`def columns`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L586) is:

```scala
  /**
   * Returns all column names as an array.
   *
   * @group basic
   * @since 1.6.0
   */
  def columns: Array[String] = schema.fields.map(_.name)
```

Which accesses, `schema` which is of type [`StructType`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.scala) and contains `field`:

```scala
case class StructType(fields: Array[StructField])
```

Since we are relying on `Array`, here; a class from the standard library, and using it's fundamental `map` method, **we can indeed rely on the ordering**.